# SQL Server 2005 Error 701 - out of memory

Tags: sql-server-2005, memory

I'm currently having following error message when executing a .sql file with about 26MB on SQL Server 2005:

```
Msg 701, Level 17, State 123
There is insufficient system memory to run this query.
```

I'm working with 4GB RAM, 64Bit Windows 7 Ultimate, Core2Duo T6400(2GHz)...

Is there a way to execute it without receiving this message (maybe force SQL Server to use swap file?) or a way to execute it in parts (like 100 queries a time)...

The file is basically a CREATE TABLE followed by thousads of INSERT queries and I have a lot of those (converted .DBF files to SQL queries using ABC DBF Converter)

Any idea will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question actually seems to come up every so often here.  [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296374/sql-server-2005-error-701-out-of-memory/2296399#2296399) has the correct (and most commonly employed) answer, but let me try to add what I can to make this clearer.

The error message is a little misleading.  SQL Server tells you that it doesn't have enough memory to *run* the query, but what it really means is that it doesn't have enough memory to **parse** the query.

When it comes to *running* the query, SQL Server can use all it wants - gigabytes if necessary.  Parsing is another story; the server has to build a parse tree and there is only a very limited amount of memory available for that.  I've never found the actual limit documented anywhere but for a typical batch full of `INSERT` statements, it can't handle more than a few MB at a time.

So I am sorry to tell you this but you *cannot* make SQL Server execute this script exactly as it is written.  No way, no how, doesn't matter what settings you tweak.  You do, however, have a number of options to work around it:

Specifically, you have three options:

1. Use `GO` statements.  This is used by SSMS and various other tools as a batch separator.  Instead of a single parse tree being generated for the entire script, individual parse trees are generated for each segment of the batch separated by `GO`.  This is what most people do, and it is very simple to still make the script transactionally-safe, as others have demonstrated and I won't repeat here.
2. Instead of generating a massive script to insert all of the rows, keep the data in a text file (i.e. comma-separated).  Then import it using the [bcp utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx).  If you need this to be "scriptable" - i.e. the import needs to happen in the same script/transaction as the `CREATE TABLE` statement, then use [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) instead.  Although `BULK INSERT` is a non-logged operation, believe it or not, it can still be placed within a `BEGIN TRAN` / `COMMIT TRAN` block.
3. If you really, really want the `INSERT` to be a logged operation, and don't want the insertions to happen in batches, then you can use [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) to open up a text file, excel file, etc. as an ad-hoc "table", and then insert this into your newly-created table.  I'm normally loath to ever recommend the use of `OPENROWSET`, but as this is clearly an administrative script, it's not really a major problem.

---

Previous comments suggest that you're uncomfortable with #1, although that may just be because of an incorrect assumption that it can't be done in a single transaction, in which case see [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296374/sql-server-2005-error-701-out-of-memory/2420907#2420907)'s answer.  But if you're dead-set on going another way, I suggest going with #2, creating a text file and using `BULK INSERT`.  An example of a "safe" script would be:

```
BEGIN TRAN

BEGIN TRY

    CREATE TABLE MyTable (...)

    BULK INSERT  MyTable
    FROM 'C:\Scripts\Data\MyTableData.txt' 
    WITH (
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n',
        BATCHSIZE = 1000,
        MAXERRORS = 1
    )

    COMMIT

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

    ROLLBACK

END CATCH
```

Hopefully this helps put you on the right track.  I'm pretty sure this covers all of your available "in the box" options - beyond these, you'd have to start writing actual application programs or shell scripts to do the work, and I don't think that level of complexity is really warranted here.

Answer (score 5):

You could break up the file into several batches - e.g. adding a go statement after every thousand inserts

e.g.

```
insert db..table( field list ) values  ...
insert db..table( field list ) values  ...
go
insert db..table( field list ) values  ...
...
insert db..table( field list ) values  ...
go
```

Another way might be you use bulk uploading e.g. bcp

Comment: Until it's edited, he means ADDING a `GO` statement after every thousand insert.

Comment: I already used GO statements to solve the problem, but I don't want to use batch-executing because if I have any error I'll have problems rollbacking transaction...

Comment: Then insert from batch into another table e.g. in tempdb and then do the main table as a insert ... select from tempdd..x

Answer (score 0):

In addition sprinkling GO statements every so many records, if you are concerned about the whole thing running or rolling back then use a transaction like so:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN TRAN

Insert ...
Insert ...
Insert ...
...
GO
Insert ..
Insert ..
Insert ..
GO

If @@TranCount > 0 Commit Tran
```

With XACT_ABORT set to ON, any insert statement that fails will rollback the entire transaction.

Answer (score -1):

You could add DBCC commands in between your sql queries like:

```
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE ('ALL')
GO
DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE
GO
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO
```

This will help release memory. Also, Microsoft release a Hotfix to address this issue in Sql Server 2005 (Look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/912439)). Try to install the Hotfix\Service Pack.